# HTMLAgilityPack getting <P> and <STRONG> text

Tags: html, vb.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

Hey all I am looking for a way to get this HTML code:

```html
<DIV class=schedule_block>
<DIV class=channel_row><SPAN class=channel>
<DIV class=logo><IMG src='/images/channel_logos/WGNAMER.png'></DIV>
<P><STRONG>2</STRONG><BR>WGNAMER </P></SPAN>
```

using the HtmlAgilityPack.

I have been trying this:

```
For Each channel In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='channel_row']")
   Dim info = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()

   With channel
      info!Logo = .SelectSingleNode(".//img").Attributes("src").Value
      info!Channel = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(0).InnerText
      info!Station = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(2).InnerText
   End With
.......
```

I can get the Logo but it comes up with a blank string for the Channel and for the Station it says

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

I've tried all types of combinations:

```
info!Station = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(1).InnerText
info!Station = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(3).InnerText
info!Station = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(1).InnerText
info!Station = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(2).InnerText
info!Station = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(3).InnerText
```

What do I need to do in order to correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the whitespace is actually there, it counts as a child node. So:

```
Dim channelSpan = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']")

info!Channel = channelSpan.ChildNodes(3).ChildNodes(0).InnerText
info!Station = channelSpan.ChildNodes(3).ChildNodes(2).InnerText
```

Comment: **Index was out of range** now for the Channel when i did that.

Comment: @StealthRT: What's `channelSpan.ChildNodes.Count`?

Comment: I do not see that listed in the "C's"? Check OP again.

Comment: @StealthRT: Expand `ChildNodes` and look for the `Count` property.

Comment: It has 4 in that... updating OP

Comment: @StealthRT: Hm... try `channelSpan.ChildNodes(3)`, then.

Comment: You got it! Thanks minitech!